# Deploying to App Engine is failing from command line

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy a Node.js application from my local workstation using the `gcloud` CLI however it's failing and I cannot figure out why. Here is the command and the response (I've obviously taken out the sensitive information):

```sh
server % gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug
Services to deploy:

descriptor:      [/.../app.yaml]
source:          [/...]
target project:  [app-id]
target service:  [default]
target version:  [20200916t171722]
target url:      [https://app-id.appspot.com]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  

Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 15 files to Google Cloud Storage               ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.

...lots these "Updating service" messages...

Updating service [default]...
DEBUG: Operation [apps/app-id/operations/15f1e5da-50dd300a8af0] not complete. Waiting to retry.
Updating service [default]...
DEBUG: Operation [apps/app-id/operations/15f1e5da-50dd300a8af0] complete. Result: {
    "done": true,
    "error": {
        "code": 13,
        "message": "Error processing user code."
    },
    "metadata": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1.OperationMetadataV1",
        "endTime": "2020-09-17T10:08:01.978Z",
        "insertTime": "2020-09-17T10:06:40.927Z",
        "method": "google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion",
        "target": "apps/app-id/services/default/versions/20200917t060633",
        "user": "me@example.com"
    },
    "name": "apps/app-id/operations/15f1e5da-50dd300a8af0"
}
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                                                                 
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Error processing user code.
```

Then I popped over into the Google Cloud "Activity" page and I see this:

```
Failed: Create service account
User (anonymized) failed to create app-id
September 16, 2020 at 5:18:36 PM GMT-4
Resource name projects/app-id
Error message Already exists (HTTP 409): ALREADY_EXISTS
Request
Account id appengine-default
Name projects/app-id
Service account
Display name App Engine default service account
Email app-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

Here's the `app.yaml`

```yaml
runtime: nodejs12
instance_class: F2

env_variables:
  SOME_VAR: "ABCDEFG"
```

I'm obviously new to App Engine and feel like I'm missing something but I can't seem to figure out what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you already created the app? This can be done by running the following command: `gcloud app create` and to get a full output message so its easier to assist you run the app deploy command with the debug flag like this: `gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug` and share the full output

Comment: I've seen a lot this issue and I suspect the issue is because you deleted the App Engine default Service account, did you?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, the app is/was already created. I edited the post with the output when running it with debug. I'll create a new project and try it there...the only explanation is I must have deleted the service accounts.

Comment: Deploying to a new project worked. I must have deleted the service accounts by accident at some point. Thanks for the help.